# What does it mean for a function $f: \mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R^m$ to be continuously differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The inverse function theorem in higher dimensions states that $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ has to be continuously differentiable, but I don't understand what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: The derivative is continuous. That's it. A slightly weaker condition than requiring the existence of a second derivative.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Formally, the derivative of such a function at a point is a matrix (or a linear transformation, as you prefer) of size $m\times n$. So the derivative being continuous means that the map from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ which returns the derivative at each point is continuous. It can be proved that this definition is equivalent to all partial derivatives of $f$ being continuous. (which is obviously something which is much easier to check)

Comment: @Mark If I could ask you a few questions: What metric do we use on $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Also is it enough to say that if each entry in the matrix is a continuous function, then the map is continuous? Can we talk about the derivative of a map from $\mathbb{R}^n \to M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Any metric which is induced from a norm is fine. (all norms are equivalent). Actually $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^{mn}}$, so you can just work in this space. This way you can indeed talk about a derivative of a map $\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^{mn}}$. And yes, if each entry is a continuous function then the map is continuous. This follows from the equivalence of norms. (just as a function $\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is continuous if and only if it is continuous in each coordinate)

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding check [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html) and [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Continuously_Differentiable)

A differentiable function $f$ is continuously differentiable if and only if $f$ is of differentiability class $C^1$.

That is if the first-order derivative of $f$ (and possibly higher) is continuous.

Comment: So in order for f:R^n->R^m to be continuously differentiable, it has to be differentiable and all delta (f_j) / delta (x_i) : R^n -> R^m, j=1...m, i=1...n, have to be continuous?

Comment: You should really put the primary content of your answer in the post (in particular, the vector-valued portion of the second link).

Comment: @Jan Note: $\frac{df_i}{dx_i}$ is **not** from $R^n$ to $R^m$ but from $R^n$ to $R$, If you are taking component-wise. Also, any function $f$ is continuous if and only if all its components are continuous (same is true for differentiability).